# Upper Limit Definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

The upper and lower limits can be defined as follows:

$$U:=\limsup_{x\to x_0} f(x)\\
L:= \liminf_{x\to x_0} f(x)$$

$L$ is characterized by the properties:

i) There is a sequence $\{y_k\} \subset E\setminus\{x_0\}$ such that $\lim y_k=x_0$ and $\lim f(y_k)=L$;

ii) For any sequence $\{y_k\} \subset E\setminus\{x_0\}$ converging to $x_0$ we have $\liminf f(y_k)\geq L$.

I was reading some upper and lower limit and came up on [this site](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Upper_and_lower_limits#Upper_and_lower_limit_of_a_real_function).

I am wondering how would I prove the above two properties since the site didn't say and I am a little confused about these defintions.

Comment: Hi. Some MathJax tips: $\limsup$ could be typed by "\limsup". Similarly for $\liminf$. To use subscripts, type "_", as in "x_0" which gives us $x_0$. Also, the backslash used to represents the set difference could be "\setminus", as in $A \setminus B$.

Comment: For the question, try to take a sequence of radius that converges to 0 in order to find a sequence $y_k$ in the definition.

Comment: thanks for the tips and so far I have defined a sequence of $g: (0,1]→R$, $g(r) :=\ inf_{x∈Br(x0)}f(x)$  and prove that the limit exists. But how would i find the sequence youre talking about?

Comment: If you use $g(r)$ instead, then the existence is obvious, because $g(r)$ is monotonic.

Comment: so i use g(r) instead why does monotonicity imply existance?

Comment: i only proved it is monotically decreasing so how do i know f(x_n) is bounded from below, not above?

Comment: My bad. Here we usually assume that $U, L \in \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty, -\infty\}$. So in a general sense, the limit exists.

Comment: got it how would i prove the second statement?

Comment: i read somewhere  $\liminf_{x→x0} f(x) := \inf_{xn→x0} \liminf_{n→∞} f(x_n)$, is this equivalent? if so, could you please give a general sense on how to prove it

Comment: Sorry, never have I seen this one. Instead, from what I know, $$\limsup _{x \to x_0} f(x) := \sup \{\ell \in \mathbb R\cup\{-\infty, +\infty\}\colon \exists x_n \to x_0 (f(x_n) \to \ell)\}. $$

Comment: and would you please explain how this definition of lim sup came from? is it related to g(r)?

Comment: I've given my answer. Hope it would help.

Answer (score 0):

#### Definitions

Provided that $x_0$ is an accumulation point of the set $E$, for $f \colon E \to \mathbb R$,
$$
U=\limsup_{x \to x_0} := \inf_{r >0} \sup_{x \in \check B_E (x_0;r)} f(x), L=\liminf _{x \to x_0} := \sup_{r >0} \inf_{x \in \check B_E (x_0;r)} f(x), 
$$
where
$$
\check B_E (x_0;r) :=\{y \in E\colon 0<|y - x_0|<r\}. 
$$

#### Propositions

For $\liminf f$, we have the following claims:

1. There is a sequence $(x_n) \subseteq E \setminus \{x_0\}$ that $x_n \to x_0$ and $f(x_n) \to L$ as $n \to \infty$;
2. For each sequence $(x_n) \subseteq E\setminus \{x_0\}$ that $x_n \to x_0$ as $n \to \infty$, $\liminf_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) \geqslant L$;
3. Equivalently, $$ \liminf_{x\to x_0} f(x)= \inf \{\ell \in \mathbb R\cup \{-\infty, +\infty\}\colon \exists (x_n) \to x_0 \text{  s.t. } f(x_n) \to \ell \}.  $$

#### Proofs

We first investigate a function
$$
g\colon (0,1]\to \mathbb R\cup\{-\infty, +\infty\}, r \mapsto \inf_{x \in \check B(x_0;r)} f(x).  
$$

Note that $g$ is monotonically decreasing, since for $0<r_1 <r_2<1$, the sets
$$
\check B_E (x_0;r_1) < \check B_E (x_0; r_2), 
$$
then
$$
\inf_{\check B_E (x_0;r_1)} f(x) \geqslant \inf_{\check B_E (x_0; r_2)} f(x). 
$$
Thus $g(0^+)$ exists, and $g(0^+) = L$ by the properties of monotonic functions.

1. For each $n$, consider $g(1/n)$, then $g(1/n) \nearrow g(0^+) = L$. For each $n$, by definition of $\inf$, there is an $x_n \in \check B_E(x_0; 1/n)$ that $g(1/n)\leqslant  f(x_n) \leqslant g(1/n)  + 1/n$. Thus by the squeezing theorem, $$ \lim_n g(1/n) \leqslant \lim_n f(x_n)  \leqslant \lim_n g(1/n) + 1/n,$$ which means $\lim_n f(x_n) = L$.
2. By the definition of $g(r)$, for each $(x_n) \subseteq E\setminus \{x_0\}$ that $x_n \to x_0$, if $r_n := |x_n - x_0|+1/n$, then $f(x_n) \geqslant g(r_n)$. By taking $\liminf$, we get $$\liminf f(x_n) \geqslant \liminf g(r_n) = \lim g(r_n) = g(0^+) = L.$$
3. Let the RHS be $L'$. According to No. 1, $L \geqslant L'$. According to No. 2, if we take a sequence $(x_n) \to x_0$ that $f(x_n) \to \ell$, then $\ell \geqslant L$, so $L \leqslant L'$. Therefore $L = L'$.